# Ошибка с токеном с библиотекой aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

[image: Это ошибки]
Ошибка в:

```
aiogram.utils.exceptions.ValidationError: Token is invalid! It must be 'str' type instead of <class 'NoneType'> type.
```

```
 from aiogram import Bot, types
 from aiogram.dispatcher import dispatcher 
 from aiogram.utils import executor

 import os


 bot = Bot(token = os.getenv('TOKEN'))
 dp = Dispatcher(bot)

 @dp.message_handler()

 async def echo_send(message : types.Message):

        await message.answer(message.text)
        # await message.reply(message.text)
        # await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 
message.text)



executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates = True)
```

Comment: Сделай принт os.getenv('TOKEN')

Comment: Сомневаюсь что в нем твой токен

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо добавить:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавь свой токен в переменную среду

```
export TOKEN=
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/743875)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в .bat файле написать "set" заглавными буквами(SET).У меня была такая же проблема,и у меня сработало

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Вместо это строки кода:

bot = Bot(token = os.getenv('TOKEN'))

Напиши так:

bot = Bot(token = TOKEN)

---

Буду благодарен, если кто объяснит для чайника, что делает метод os.getenv и почему в данном случае он не используется? Читал документацию на английском, ничего не понял (

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B